# mat-autocomplete option not selected

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, form-control, mat-autocomplete

I have an input form with an autocomplete. It filters options as the user types. The problem is that when an option is clicked, the field goes blank instead of it being populated with the user's selection.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <mat-form-field class="w-100 mt-25" [class.input-disabled]="form.get('JobAddressID')?.disabled">
    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="*Select previously used address" formControlName="JobAddressID" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete (optionSelected)="onSelectionChanged($event)" #auto="matAutocomplete" class="w-100" [displayWith]="displayAddressSelection">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let elem of savedLocationsFiltered | async" [value]="elem">
        {{elem | truncateString: 60}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete> 
  </mat-form-field>
```

Here is my typescript file:

```
// A bunch of import statements here

@Component({
  selector: 'job-location-auth',
  templateUrl: './job-location-auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./job-location-auth.component.scss', '../../shared/css/tool-tip.scss']
})
export class JobLocationAuthComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  form: FormGroup;
  jobAddressID: FormControl;
  savedLocations: Observable<{name: string; value: string}[]>;
  savedLocationsArray: string[] = [];
  savedLocationsFiltered: Observable<string[]>;

  private subs = new SubSink();

  constructor(
    private jobAddressesService: JobAddressesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initialize();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subs.unsubscribe();
  }

  initialize(): void {
    this.form = this.locationModel.formGroup;
    this.setJobAddressControl();
    this.formAddress = this.form.get('JobAddress') as FormGroup;
    this.getAddressList();
    this.handleSavedLocationSub();
    this.filterAddresses();
  }

  setJobAddressControl(): void {
    /* tslint:disable */
    this.jobAddressID = this.form.get('JobAddressID') as FormControl;
    /* tslint:enable */
    this.subs.sink = this.jobAddressID.valueChanges.subscribe((value: number) => {
      if (value) {
        this.analyticsLoggingService.TrackEvent('JobDetails', 'JobAddress', 'Selected');
      }
      this.setAddress(+value);
    });
  }

  getAddressList(): void {
    this.savedLocations = this.jobAddressesService.getAddresses();
  }

  handleSavedLocationSub(): void {
    this.savedLocations.subscribe(
      (addresses: {name: string; value: string}[]) => this.populateSavedAddressArray(addresses)
    );
  }

  filterAddresses(): void {
    const jobAddress = this.form.get('JobAddressID');
    if (jobAddress) {
      this.savedLocationsFiltered = jobAddress.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
    }
  }

  displayAddressSelection(subject: any): string | undefined {
    return subject ? subject.name : undefined;
  }

  onSelectionChanged(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    const jobAddress = this.form.get('JobAddressID');
    if (!!jobAddress) {
      jobAddress.setValue(event.option.viewValue);
      // this.setAddress(jobAddress.value);
    }
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.savedLocationsArray.filter(location => { if (!!location) { return location.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue); } });
  }
}
```

I am not sure what's wrong. I reviewed the angular-material documentation for autocomplete, and as far as I can tell, I am following the code examples as closely as possible, so there must be some other issue going on with my code here.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anything wrong here except for this part. `[class.input-disabled]="form.get('JobAddressID')?.disabled"` Only concern for me is wether it is disabling the DOM. Try removing `[class.input-disabled]="form.get('JobAddressID')?.disabled"` and see. If it didnt work delete the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work but I appreciate it anyway.

Comment: Can you add this to stackblitz and share this please?